# Is it wrong to state that $\log(0) = -\infty$?

Tags: logarithms

[wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%280%29) states that $\log(0) = -\infty$
According to [this QA](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116622/why-are-logarithms-not-defined-for-0-and-negatives) as well as [this website](http://www.mclph.umn.edu/mathrefresh/logs3.html#) by the university of Minnesota $\log(0)$ is not defined. On the other hand, the definition on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Definition) states nothing about zero.
And a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.07413.pdf) I am currently reading uses $\log(D)$ where $D \in \{0,1\}$.

So now, I'm confused as to which way is correct. Or does it depend on the context where one applies the log and both definitions ("undefined" and "$-\infty$") are common?

Comment: The wiki states very clearly that $\log_b(a)$ is defined as a solution to $b^x=a$. Which is correct and no such solution exists for $b\neq 0$ and $a=0$. No, $\log(0)$ is not well defined. Sometimes people write $\log(0)=-\infty$ to denote that $\log(x)\to -\infty$ when $x\to 0$.

Comment: If an author explicitly defines the natural log function so that $\log(0) = -\infty$ then I'd say it's fine, as long as they're consistent.

Comment: @littleO So would it be reasonable for me to assume that the author means $log(0)=-\infty$ when they did not define it at all but do use it? In the end, I'm asking this question because I'm unsure whether I should question my understanding of the paper - it would make sense for minus infinity.

Comment: Yes, I would guess that the author has defined their natural log function so that $\log(0) = -\infty$, and perhaps the author forgot to mention this.

Comment: @littleO Thank you for your help. I'm not too familiar with math.SE site culture - would you like to write your comments as an answer so that I can accept it? Or would that not be considered an answer because it's just "I'd say it's fine" and not based on sources?

Comment: @lucidbrot I'll probably not post an answer in this case; feel free to either accept Wuestenfux's answer or post your own answer and accept it if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \log(x) = -\infty$.